# Python Celery get task status

Tags: python, celery

Have this code and setup Celery with RabbitMQ

Tasks get created and executed. I get task uuid,but somehow cannot check task statuses

```
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from flask import Flask, json, g, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from celery import Celery
import os
import time


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
  'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': './client_secrets.json',
  'OIDC_RESOURCE_SERVER_ONLY': True,
  'CELERY_BROKER_URL': 'amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@rabbit:5672/',
  'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND': 'rpc://'
})
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
CORS(app)

client = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
client.conf.update(app.config)



@client.task()
def removeUser(id):
  time.sleep(10);


@app.route("/removeUser", methods=['GET'])
def removeUserID():
  id = request.args.get('id')
  result = removeUser.apply_async(args=[id], countdown=60)
  return result.id
  

@app.route("/checkStatus", methods=['GET'])
def checkStatus():
  uuid = request.args.get('uuid') 
  res = removeUser.AsyncResult(uuid)
  print(uuid)
  if(res=="SUCCESS"):
    return "success"
  else:
    return "progress"

def json_response(payload, status=200):
  return (json.dumps(payload), status, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

res = removeUser.AsyncResult(uuid) does not seem to get task status. How to get it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncResult` is an object and [state property](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.state) is what you want:

```
@app.route("/checkStatus", methods=['GET'])
def checkStatus():
  uuid = request.args.get('uuid') 
  res = removeUser.AsyncResult(uuid)
  print(uuid)
  if res.state == "SUCCESS":
    return "success"
  else:
    return "progress"
```

**Notes:**

1. Task might fail as well so that there's a better way to check if the task has executed (rather than compare to "SUCCESS").
2. If you'll add the celery app you don't have to use a specific task and this function can help you to get the state of any celery task by uuid.

```
@app.route("/checkStatus", methods=['GET'])
def checkStatus():
  uuid = request.args.get('uuid') 
  res = AsyncResult(uuid, app=client)
  print(uuid)
  if res.ready():
    return "success"
  else:
    return "progress"
```